# Method for determining which of two related continous variables has a stronger association with a third continous variable

Tags: regression, association-measure

I have two continuous variables and would like to determine which of these is more strongly associated with a third continuous variable.

I realize I could perhaps do a multiple regression and see if both remain significant in this model but I fear my two independent variables are rather correlated to each other and collinearity would be a problem. Is there any other statistical way I can determine a difference? Can you compare two single regressions somehow? Or any other completely different test?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Carl. I would be reluctant to use correlation (or the equivalent, like $R^2$) to assess strength of association without first inspecting the scatterplots for outliers and high-leverage points.  Regardless, do you really need a test?  Why wouldn't it suffice to pick the variable with the largest (*absolute*) correlation with the third variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the information for a null hypothesis statistical test (NHST) a single-sample test comparing 2 correlations (this comes from Kleinbaum, Kupper, Nizam & Rosenberg, 5th ed.).

If you wish to test the claim that two single-sample correlations (same variable correlated with 2 other variables) are different from each other,
$$H_o : \rho_{y,x_1} = \rho_{y,x_2}$$
we can using the following test statistic (for sufficiently large $n$):
$$Z = \frac{(r_1-r_2)\times\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{(1-r_1^2)^2+(1-r_2^2)^2-2r_{12}^3-(2r_{12}-r_1r_2)(1-r_1^2-r_2^2-r_{12}^2)}}$$
where $r_i$ is the correlation of $y$ and $x_i$ and $r_{12}$ is the correlation of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: From experience (personally, and watching many students make this mistake)...be sure to note the cubed correlation in the denominator...it is easy to mistype it as just another squared value.

Comment: This null isn't quite right, because it ought to concern comparison of the *absolute* correlation coefficients.

Comment: If the null is associated with a 2-tailed test, the test statistic can be positive or negative...I don't see what the issue is.  The sign (or order of the subtraction) would be more important if it were a 1-tailed/directional NHST.

Comment: The issue is that a correlation of $-1/2$ and a correlation of $+1/2$ are *identically* strong, whereas your test would likely declare them to be significantly different even for small $n.$

Comment: I will leave this to the OP to clarify...they indicate at the first about strength of association, and later in the post they ask about determining a difference (of regressions)...which I took to mean the correlations.  The reference I cite addresses this later query.

Comment: In any linear model, practically by definition any measure of the "strength" of the association must survive any invertible linear transformation of the explanatory variables. In a univariate OLS model that implies merely negating $x$ will not change the strength.  Because negating $x$ negates $\rho,$ the approach that makes sense in this context, and should be considered the default (barring any additional restriction that would prohibit negating $x$), is to compare *absolute values* of correlation coefficients.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies so far and sorry for not updating sooner.

To clarify, I am trying to determine if using one type of measurement is a better proxy compared to using another one. A bad (but hopefully illustrative example) is if its would be better to measure length or the width of the head to determine which size baseball cap to buy. So I want to compare how they both associate to head size/circumfrence and determine which one has a stronger association thus arguing for that it would be better to use that measurement. Any more help is much appreciated!